# Refresh screen after drawing a line in c#

Tags: c#, windows, screen, line, draw

I´m trying to write a simple application that prints a line "moving" at certain speed, it is my first time using c# and Windows to create an application, i found a tutorial that helps me drawing a line and so far i got this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
        static void draw(Rectangle r, Brush b, IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hwnd))
            {

                g.FillRectangle(b, r);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 0;
            while (true)
            {

                draw(new Rectangle(x, 0, 50, 1080), Brushes.PaleGoldenrod, GetDC(IntPtr.Zero));
                x++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that i don´t know how to erase the previous line, or just refresh the screen after drawing a line.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer, with that method of "drawing", you don't.  Those lines get erased by whatever you drew on top off.  That could be the desktop itself, or other application windows.  When they redraw themselves then the lines will be erased.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know a method i can use in order to achieve this? thanks!

Comment: Step one: Throw away the tutorial and clean the link! Read up on Paint event and Timer Tick

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormDrawGraphics
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // initialization
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            // Create pen.
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

            // Create points that define line.
            Point point1 = new Point(100, 100);
            Point point2 = new Point(500, 100);

            // Draw line to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);

            // add any other graphics drawing...
        }
    }
}
```

If you resize your window, or hide it and redisplay it for example, it will redraw the line.

Note: this would be for a WinForms GUI app, and not a console app that you have created.